# How to programmatically create Map of Map of Map nested in up to N times in Java/Scala

Tags: java, scala, dictionary, hashmap

How to programmatically create Map of Map of Map up to N times based on value N > 1.

I know we can create Single Map with

```
val singleMap = mutable.HashMap[String,Int]
```

Map of Map with following code

```
val mapOfMap = mutable.HashMap[Map[String,Int],Int]
```

Similarly I can create statically map of maps in code, but.
How do I create Map of Map programmatically?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: It sounds like you want to create a tree of Maps.

Comment: @EdwardPeters I need to keep track of subtypes and its count. And these subtypes can have its own subtypes. I am thinking about using Tree too. But Question is,  Is it possible to define Map dynamically like this?

Comment: @PeterLawrey - What if inner Map created has different types? In tree all nodes are going to be of same type. Map allows me to define different Key and Value types. Nested Maps allows me to further define different type of value. Tree won't allow it. I am exploring how Tree can be used for my problem. But question is it possible to  define Map dynamically like this?

Comment: I'm having some trouble following what you're describing. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: Scala is statically typed. What you want to do looks like having dynamic type declared as static type. It obviously doesn't make sense. You have to give up type information on certain level of your map: `val m: Map[Map[String, Int], Map[_, _]] = Map()`

Comment: @EdwardPeters - Can you define nested Maps dynamically. I showed it in example how two level nested Map can be defined. Similarly how to define N level nested Map programmatically?

Comment: No, like Aivean said, Java/Scala are statically typed... I don't believe it's possible to programmatically build a new type. But, I also don't think that's what you really want to do... if I understood the problem you were working on, I might be able to help you find a better approach.

Comment: @Aivean thanks for the input. Yes Scala is statically typed. I forgot that I won't be able to do different type of Map key,value. What if I keep same Key, Value?  What about in Java?

Comment: @EdwardPeters Thanks for showing interest. I posted more detailed problem description related to this here -  [36316216](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316216/what-data-structure-is-best-suited-for-nested-values-and-count-of-values)

Answer (score 0):

In a Java you would defined this as

```
Map<String, Object> root = new HashMap<>();
```

for each level, you need to use a cast because you know (and the JVM doesn't) how many levels you can navigate.

```
Object value = root.get(key);
if (value instanceof Map) {
   Map<String, Object> nested = (Map) value;
}
```

In short, Java and Scala are statically typed languages.  You cannot specific a type which is only known at runtime and expect the compiler to deal with this.